# Button delete and restore button from MATLAB GUIDE error

Tags: matlab, radio-button, matlab-guide, radio-group

I had a MATLAB GUIDE interface ready for an experiment, and I had two radio button groups. Suddenly I deleted a radio button group, saved the file, and then did a "undo" to the radio button groups, and re-ran my code again, and all of a sudden my GUIDE interface doesn't find the radio button group that are clearly restored back again in the GUIDE.

I'm confused because the .m and the .fig file look the same, and I can't seem to spot the error. I don't get an error when I run the .m function, but I do get an error when I select one of the "deleted/restored" radio buttons:

```
Error using handle.handle/get
Invalid or deleted object.

Error in uitools.uibuttongroup/childAddedCbk>manageButtons (line 59)
oldctrl = get(hgroup, 'OldSelectedObject');

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

How do I restore my previous configuration file? Is there something I can do with the property inspector for all my radio buttons as a sanity check?

Comment: I've got a feeling the radio button group's `Tag` is different between the M-file and what the Property Inspector will tell you when you examine the buttongroup.

Comment: I just checked and they are the same, that is why I'm banging my head against the wall!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting enough, what I had to do was delete the "undo-ed" radio button. And create new one's. So it looks like the undo-redo sequence kind of bugs the button groups.